# React Native Expo show all the images taken by the camera and save them

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I want to show all the images taken by the exposure camera in a list in the same view of the application and save them

currently when taking the photo I keep and show the photo but it is not saved in the view of the app, if it is saved in the gallery of images of the mobile, but I want to show a list of all the photos taken and that the view is saved. in the application with all the photos taken from that view,

what you should do to show in a view of the application all the photos taken?

this is my code

```
async takePicture() {
    const result = await ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync({
      allowEditing: false,
      exif: true
    });

    if (!result.cancelled) {
      this.setState({ image: result.uri });
    }
    CameraRoll.saveToCameraRoll(this.state.image);
  };
```

```
render() {
    const { hasCameraPermission, image } = this.state

    if (hasCameraPermission === null) {
      return <View />;
    } else if (hasCameraPermission === false) {
      return <Text>No access to camera</Text>;
    } else {
      return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, width: '100%', height: '100%' }}>
          <Button
            title={t('buttons:takeaPhoto')}
            titleStyle={index.titleButtonStyle}
            containerStyle={{
              margin: 0,
              paddingTop: 10,
              paddingHorizontal: 10
            }}
            buttonStyle={index.buttonStyle}
            onPress={() => this.takePicture() }
          />
          { image &&
            <View>
              <Image style={styles.image} source={{ uri: this.state.image }} />

            </View>
          }
        </View>
      );
    }
  }
```

Comment: I think you should save them in local storage or Database that you can have persistent storage of your images, because updating the component for each taking picture  will remove the previous image and rerender the component